# Missing something between datetime comparisons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here is my code:

```
@if (item.eventinfo != null)
{
    if (item.eventinfo.start_date <= DateTime.Today && item.eventinfo.end_date >= DateTime.Today)
    {
        <div class="event-info>">
            <span style="color: red;"><strong>EVENT HAPPENING NOW</strong> through @item.eventinfo.end_date.ToShortDateString()<br />in stock during events only.</span>
        </div>
    }
    else if (item.eventinfo.start_date > DateTime.Today)
    {
        <div class="event-info>">
            <span style="color: red;"><strong>Next Event</strong>: @item.eventinfo.start_date.ToShortDateString() through @item.eventinfo.end_date.ToShortDateString()<br />in stock during events only.</span>
        </div>
    }
}
```

I have an event in my database set for today. `2014-10-16 14:02:36.827`

When I ran the page I expected to see EVENT HAPPENING NOW.  But instead I see Next Event: 10/16/2014.

I'm guessing it is something odd between comparing the two date times.  Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: your question doesn't make sense. you say you have a date of `2014-10-26`, but you expect to see `EVENT HAPPENING NOW`?

Comment: Copied end date instead of start date should have been 10/16/2014

Comment: Why aren't you using `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: @Michael_B because I didn't want time to be a factor.  Since the event time doesn't really matter.  I just wanted to compare event date to todays date.

Comment: I found out the solution.  Not sure if this is what @ps2goat was meaning.  but all I had to do was do `item.eventinfo.start_date.Date`

Comment: and James this I would ask again why you are not using DateTime.Now and check for the Date portion.. I do not think you're understanding the power of C#'s Date / DateTime Declare your variable as a `Date` boooooooooooooooo James Booooooooooooo

Comment: @DJKRAZE then perhaps give me an example?  As im aware datetime.now gives you todays date with the time, whereas datetime.today only gives you todays date and I only need to compare the date....

Comment: you are aware now you mean.. otherwise you would have implemented that initially in my opinion..but nice try...

Comment: As @JamesWilson stated, he does not care about the time portion of the date. `Today` returns just the date, `Now` returns the date + time.  Yes, James, performing `.Date` on a DateTime variable will return the truncated Date.  If you do not care about times, though, you should be declaring your variables as `Date` instead of `DateTime`, and you should be storing the values in the database as `date` instead of `datetime`.  It will save you quite a bit of space in the database, and it gets rid of the extra time info.

Comment: @ps2goat That is where I am lacking then.  Thank you for the extra help, nice to see some help and good tips rather than....  :)

Comment: @DJKRAZE, there's no need to be nasty on here. James is trying to understand what's going on.  If you want to provide some useful information, do so in an answer-- NOT as a holier-than-thou comment.

Comment: I am not being nasty.. I am just responding in regards to what I think that he just discovered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that your start date is greater than `Today`, which is a date of `2014-10-16` with a time value of midnight (0:00:00).

If you trim the date, or declare it as a `Date` on your model vs. a `DateTime`, you should get the result you are looking for.